# How do I create extra permissions for an eck created entity?

Tags: 7, users, routes, entities

I have created an entity using [Entity Construction Kit (ECK)](http://drupal.org/project/eck) and wish to add extra permissions for that entity such as view own, edit own and delete own. I see there has been some movement in this thread [Better Permissions](http://drupal.org/node/1374150) and a few others to create better permissions in general for entities but I want to know how can I do it in my own custom module.

I do not want every person on the site to be able to view,edit,delete so I have disabled those perms for my created entity.

I'm stuck and cannot find any good documentation on it.

Comment: [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access) does that for nodes, it's source could give an example.

Answer (score 6):

You need to alter the entity info using:

```
hook_entity_info_alter
```

and add the access callback

e.g:

```
function EXAMPLE_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['my_entity']['access callback'] = 'my_entity_access';
}
```

and then in my_entity_access

```
function my_entity_access($op, $entity = NULL, $account = NULL) {
  switch($op){
    case 'view':
    // view check
    // e.g return user_access('view my_entity', $account);
    break;
    case 'create':
    // create check
    break;
    case 'update':
    // update check
    break;
    case 'delete':
    // delete check
    break;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

See [node_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_access/7) for more info

You may want to use [hook_permission](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) to define your own permissions also.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```
function my_permission() {
  return array(
    'view own forum post' => array(
      'title' => t('View own forum post'),
      'description' => t('View own forum post.'),
    ),
    'edit own forum post' => array(
      'title' => t('Edit own forum post'),
      'description' => t('Edit own forum post.'),
    ),
    'delete own forum post' => array(
      'title' => t('Delete own forum post'),
      'description' => t('Delete own forum post.'),
    ),
  );
}

function my_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['forum']['access callback'] = 'my_forum_access';
}

function my_forum_access($op, $entity) {

  global $user;

  $entity_type = $op == 'create' ? $entity : $entity->type;

  if (eck__entity_access($op, $entity_type, $user, 'forum')) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  if ($entity && $entity_type == 'forum_post') {
    switch ($op) {
      case 'view':
        if (user_access('view own forum post', $user) && $user->uid == $entity->uid) {
          return TRUE;
        }
        break;
      case 'update':
        if (user_access('edit own forum post', $user) && $user->uid == $entity->uid) {
          return TRUE;
        }
        break;
      case 'delete':
        if (user_access('delete own forum post', $user) && $user->uid == $entity->uid) {
          return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference to the own functionality through eck's own behavior system, in the "better permissions" issue you mentioned above. Check it out and give us some feedback.